# Twitter follower demographics?

Tags: twitter

Any ideas on how I can get location, age and gender of my followers on Twitter? I know that Twitter can only give me location (not always), by looking at either time-zone or location. But I have seen other applications presenting the demographics of my followers and I have no idea how they do it? Is it fake?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter does not provide this information. Some third party sites use techniques like analyzing tweets to try and predict demographics based on content. Others have deals with third partys that connect Twitter accounts with other profiles like Facebook accounts. There is no sure fire way to do it and all options will have reliability issues.